# GDAL подключить к Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gdal

Пытаюсь подключить GDAL к своему Qt проекту на C++. Пробовал скачивать исходники и собирать, но получал ошибки. Тогда скачал готовую версию отсюда : https://www.gisinternals.com/release.php

Подключил и запустил проект. Не хватало нескольких dll. Я положил их в папку с исполняемым файлом и теперь просто не запускается с ошибкой

[image: Ошибка]

Я понимаю, что не хватает каких-то dll, но не знаю каких.

До этого брал GDAL со всем необходимым из QGIS. Все работало, но была ошибка **undefined reference OGRSpatialReference**, поэтому решил взять GDAL из другого места.

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне бороться с этим.

Для справки: windows 10, qmake, qt creator самый свежий.

Comment: GDAL мне нужен для решения задачи получения широты, долготы и высоты из пикселя в tiff файле

Comment: Используйте Dependency walker для определения зависимостей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя боль и страдания мне удалось собрать и подключить самую свежую (3.6.3) версию gdal. Но получилось на debian linux. Думаю такой же алгоритм подойдет и на windows.

Здесь: https://gdal.org/development/dev_environment.html указаны минимальные требования для сборки.

Далее. Отсюда https://gdal.org/development/building_from_source.html взял параметры для минимальной сборки: `-DGDAL_BUILD_OPTIONAL_DRIVERS=OFF -DOGR_BUILD_OPTIONAL_DRIVERS=OFF` и запустил с ними cmake, как сказано в туториале.

Как обычно получил ошибку, что не хватает тонны библиотек.

Поочередно начал устанавливать библиотеки и после установки PROJ, gdal собрался. **Скорее всего можно было просто установить PROJ, так как ошибки по библиотекам пропали после его установки.**

Дальше установил командами, как написано в туториале, и подключил в Qt проект. Все работает.

На Windows можно попробовать поколдовать в msys2 таким же методом, так как там похожее на linux окружение.

**Тут есть важный момент: может быть такое, что библиотека уже установлена, но при сборке пишет, что ее нет. Тогда нужно скачать исходники библиотеки. Например: у меня писало, что нет ZLIB, хотя он был. Тогда я установил zlib1g-dev, в которой были файлы для разработчиков и gdal при сборке таки нашел ZLIB.**

Comment: `*-dev` тем и отличается от обычной версии, что необходима для разработки или билда. Потому что содержит не просто исполняемый файл, а `*.a`/`*.lib` и `*.so`/`*.dll` файлы и хэдеры. Под виндой лучше всегда собирать зависимости одним компилятором.

Answer (score 0):

Докладываю: сегодня **собрал gdal 3.7.2** на debian 11. Все собралось без проблем и подключилось к Qt.
Что я сделал:

1. Скачал последний релиз (https://gdal.org/download.html)
2. Распаковал и создал отдельную пустую папку.
3. Установил `libproj-dev` и `zlib-dev` через `apt install`.
4. Сделал все по туториалу из пустой папки (https://gdal.org/development/building_from_source.html).

Все собралось успешно. После сборки в командной строке будет написано где и что создалось (в моем случае создалось в `/usr/local/include`). Далее нужно дописать путь до нужных библиотек уже в Qt проекте, чтобы можно было подключать их к вашим `.cpp` и `.h` файлам.

Comment: Также нужно убедиться, что установлены доп.компоненты:
`sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev`
`sudo apt-get install build-essential`